# Why do I even need DeepWalk and Node2Vec when I can build a visual graph structure?

Tags: machine-learning, graphical-model, graph-theory, graph-neural-network

While studying DeepWalk, I started wondering why I need "DeepWalk" when I can build a graph from data and visualize the structure of a graph. With a visualized graph, I can see which nodes are neighbors to which nodes from the graph visualization, then again, I wonder why I need "DeepWalk" when I can visualized a graph and see neighbors of nodes. Can somebody tell me why I need "DeepWalk" to see which nodes are close which nodes when I can visualize them and see their neighbors, respectively?

Comment: What if you have a truly massive graph? What if you want to use structural information in some subsequent computational process, instead of visualizing it for a human?

Comment: @Sycorax 
What could be examples of some subsequent computational processes?

Comment: Any model that works on tabular data instead of graph data could use the DeepWalk network as a feature extraction tool, then provide the extracted features to another model (e.g. random forest), possibly enriched by some other sources of information or types of data. Or you might want to do similarity search or recommendation or clustering... basically anything.

Comment: I just understood I can do clustering using node embedding with DeepWalk, you seem to say I can also do classification using the embedded features with the target variable such as diabetes or obesity included in the training dataset, supposing I use Random Forest, for example. Have I correctly understood you?

Comment: Basically. Your question was essentially asks "Why do I need numerical information when I can visualize my data?" but there are lots of things that are either hard to visualize or where visualization is not the desired end-goal.

Answer (score 1):

A visualization of your graph (a "2D graph embedding") usually cannot display all the similarities by means of the closeness of the nodes. That's because it is only two-dimensional.